# group by successive days

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a table of actions , eache action has two dates, startDate and endDate, 
i want to writ a request that groupe by day , **but in a successive manner**

Exemple :

```
action ;  startDate ;  endDate

Action1 ; 2012-10-10 ; 2012-10-10

Action2 ; 2012-10-10 ; 2012-10-12

Action3 ; 2012-10-14 ; 2012-10-15
```

my request is

```
SELECT DAY(startDate), COUNT(Name) FROM ActionTable 
WHERE startDate < '2012-10-09' and endDate > '2012-10-15'
GROUP BY DAY(startDate)
```

This request return me that :

```
10 ; 2

14 ; 1
```

I need a request to get this results

```
10 ; 2

11 ; 1

12 ; 1

14 ; 1

15 ; 1
```

so if an Action is in three days a need that I get +1 in each day

Comment: What if you use group by day(), or group by day(startDate), day(endDate) ?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it give it the result you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to solve this is to have a separate table with all of the days:

```
CREATE TABLE `days` (
  `day` date NOT NULL
)
```

where you have already inserted all of the days you want to group (for example, the whole month):

```
INSERT INTO `days` (`day`) VALUES
  ('2012-10-10'),
  ('2012-10-11'),
  ('2012-10-12'),
  ('2012-10-13'),
  etc.
```

and then run this query:

```
SELECT days.day, count(*) as cnt
FROM
  days LEFT JOIN actions
  ON days.day >= actions.startDate and days.day <= endDate
GROUP BY days.day
HAVING Count(*)>0
```

Comment: if you can't create new tables, i don't think there's an easy solution to this... at least, not with plain sql. You could replace days table with something like (select DATE('2012-10-10) union select DATE('2012-10-11') union select DATE('etc')) but i don't think i like this solution much....

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea

i think to creat for each day a new count, and formating dates by name 
(monday ....)

so i will get for each day a colomn of results

my startDate ;  endDate are the two limits of the week